# Sequential iteration over multiple inputs

Tags: r, purrr

This seems like it should be straightforward. I have got 2 lists, a list of 3 experiments and 3 replicates in each experiment. What I'd like to do is to read in all 9 replicates in one go:

```
library(purrr)
x = list("exp1", "exp2", "exp3")
y = list("rep1", "rep2", "rep3")
```

Using `map()` e.g.:

```
map(x, function(x){paste(x, map(y, paste0))})
```

However, if i try `map2(x, y, paste)` I get only 3 parallel iterations of both inputs.

Is there no easy way of doing this in one `map2` call rather than nesting map iterations? Thanks.

Comment: With `dplyr` you could inner join on a dummy column then `paste` the result. Similarly using `CJ` (cross join) from `data.table`.

Comment: This kind of does what you want `map2(x,y,~paste(x,y))`, however the binding occurs per row rather than finding all combinations of y per x.

Comment: Sorry @timfaber but this just replicates my `map2(x, y, paste)` call three times.

Comment: By the way, your nested call can be written `map(x, ~paste(.x, map(y, paste0)))`.

Comment: In base R, you can use `outer` like this to return a vector of all pairs pasted together: `c(outer(x, y, FUN=paste))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly generate the different combinations, for example using `expand.grid`:

```
expand.grid(x = x, y = y) %>% { map2(.$x, .$y, paste) }
```

Comment: Better than nesting map calls, I agree. Thanks.